# Problems with boolean DependencyProperty not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I created a usercontrol called BilLister with a DependencyProperty called Active:

```
<cbtn:BillLister 
    x:Name="euro500"     
    Active="true" />
<cbtn:BillLister 
    x:Name="euro200"
    Active="false" />
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

From the component:

```
public bool Active
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ActiveProperty); }
    set {                    
        SetValue(ActiveProperty, value); 
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Active", typeof(bool),
        typeof(BillLister), new PropertyMetadata((bool)false, 
        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSomeValuePropertyChanged)));
```

In the function that is called i put this:

```
private static void OnSomeValuePropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BillLister numericBox = target as BillLister;
    switch (e.Property.ToString())
    {            
        case "Active":
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
                    numericBox.CurrencyImage.Opacity = 1;
                else
                    numericBox.CurrencyImage.Opacity = 0.50;
                break;                
    }         
}
```

However, the e.NewValue always returns true. I also put other items in the switch, which are handled correctly, but it seems the boolean is not being passed correctly.

Does anyone have any idea why it's always passing true? I would expect a false at least because of the false i'm passing where i'm registering the dependency property.

Thanks!!

Comment: Initially `OnSomeValuePropertyChanged` won't be called for false as it's default value for `bool` so effectively value does not change. It will be called only when previous value was true. Normally you would **create `Style` in XAML for `CurrencyImage` with trigger on `Active` property** where you change `Opacity`

Comment: You will not get false. Because your default value is false. When the false change to true then only property change will happen. If you really want to achieve this you can use a enum or a Nullable bool.

Comment: You are both completely right!!! I changed the default to true and now he triggers on the one that is false and sets it's opacity correctly.
Also the idea of applying a different style when Changing the Active property is a good one, because this component will get more complex in the future.